# Using SDWebImage and saving image to public gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage for my iOS project. SDWebImage has great features to cache the picture in the memory as well as in the disk when extracting pictures based on URL. However, could we also make the pictures (cached by SDWebImage) available in the picture galley? This allows the user to view the picture they downloaded using the photo galley and also allows other apps to use the pictures as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image after SDWebImage loads it into your UIImageView like this:

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
    placeholderImage:placeholder 
    options:options
    progress:nil
    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (image) {
            // save to photo album here
        }
    }
];
```

I use this library to save photos to a custom photo album:

https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum

Here is sample code using this library:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary saveImage:image toAlbum:@"YOUR_ALBUM_NAME" completion:nil failure:nil];
```

**Update**: You can use the ALAssetsLibrary to load images from the album as well. Here is an example:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary loadImagesFromAlbum:^(NSMutableArray *images, NSError *error) {
    if (images) {
        // ...
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. After storing the photo to a custom photo album using ALAssetsLibrary, do you update the access to SDWebImage to point to your custom photo album instead? Since the photo is now available locally. I believe SDWebImage has an expiration date for caching in the disk (I might be wrong).

Comment: Depends on your use case really. If you are going to delete the image at the URL then this might make sense, but if other people still need to access it, I wouldn't  bother.

Comment: Might over complicate your code for not a lot of benefit.

Comment: Yea, I do understand. In my case, I wanted to do this for several reasons. First, is to prevent using double the disk usage, when the image has been cached in the disk and also locally stored in the album. Apart from that, the disk cache has an expiration time handled by SDWebImage, therefore after the expiration, SDWebImage would re-fetch the image although it has been locally stored on the phone. This would not be optimized for the user after the user has already stored a lot of images locally. The app network usages would increase in time as the user has more images downloaded.

Comment: Makes sense. I've mostly used this for social network type apps where users see a feed of photos and they have the ability to save photos to their device. After a couple of days they no longer see those same photos in their feed because they see newer images. So, in my case loading from the device would be overkill. If users are viewing the same photos over and over again it would make more sense to do what you are proposing. You will need to check if it exists in the library first and if it doesn't load from the URL.

Comment: You can use the ALAssetsLibrary to load images from the library as well. I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark. However, it would be good if we can directly direct SDWebImage to get the image from the photo album instead of fetching it from the URL anymore. Is there any method to dynamically update the link to point to the local stored picture after it has been successfully downloaded?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can probably use the SDWebImage caching APIs to figure out a way to cache permanently, but it won't be stored in the user's camera roll.

Comment: @markwatsonatx, I have the almost same question with this, but I using sdwebimageswiftui. 

I want get the uiimage of remote and save it to the photo library, onSuccess is a good solution, but I found that onSuccess is not executed if already cached, I cannot get the uiimage from here every time. Is this a issue or is there another solution for this?

`WebImage(url: URL(string: "https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/content/images/ski_jump_1440x960.heic"))
        .onSuccess { image, cacheType in
            // Success
        }`